# How do I get the correct close vote count in Data Explorer?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, data-explorer

**Main question:** (was previously secondary question)

How would I get the **correct** number of close votes currently on a question in Data Explorer (subject to DE caching of course)?

I now believe the below to likely be caused by vote expiration (due to users selecting 'Leave Open' on the review queue) (feel free to say otherwise if this is not the case), so, since this didn't have an (undeleted) answer, I've changed this to ask the above.

**Elaboration:**

I was just running some Data Explorer queries, but found the vote counts to be inaccurate.

[The data explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/147962/get-unclosed-questions-with-closed-votes) says there are 3 close vote (in total, all after reopening), but the post only says there is one.

[image]

[The post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980571/linux-server-help-php-include) has less than 100 views (which will probably change a few minutes from now), so the votes shouldn't have expired.

[image]

Nothing new in [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7980571/revisions)...

[image]

Can someone explain this?

(Note that all activity is more than a year ago, i.e. it's unlikely to be because Data Explorer's results are a bit old)

[Here's a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/147968/get-unclosed-questions-with-closed-votes) that shows all votes (not just close votes), if that's helpful:

[image]

It's seemingly missing the initial moderator close, but, even if the dates are incorrect and one of the later ones are it, there's still one missing vote.

Comment: [Caching!](http://jsfiddle.net/michaelb958/vSfXT/show/light/#caching) (No, really. DE data can be up to a week old.)

Comment: The dump is from the 10th.

Comment: @michaelb958 All activity is more than a year ago though.

Comment: Close votes start expiring when the question reaches 100 views or has gone through the close review queue. A mod could find the close review entry and see if that review is completed.

Comment: @Gilles "has gone through the close review queue" - when 5 users say "Leave Open", or something like that, right? (I forgot about that)

Comment: @Dukeling Yes, that's it. If 5 users say “leave open” then the existing close votes aren't erased but that starts their expiration clock ticking (if it wasn't already).

Comment: @Gilles I'll just assume that that's what happened (but someone's still free to correct me, and explain what happened, if this is not the case). I've changed my question to primarily ask how to get the correct count now as that's what I'm primarily interested in.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons that there may be a discrepancy in what a correctly coded SEDE query shows and that of what the actual question shows.

- caching
- expired close votes (*after 100 views close votes can start dropping off*)
- retracted close votes

I'm not 100% sure about what Dukeling mentioned, that if 5 users click leave open then it will start erasing close votes, *the expiration clock*. But yea, that could be another reason if that's the case.

> How would I get the correct number of close votes currently on a
> question in Data Explorer (subject to DE caching of course)?

I use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/203775/questions-with-pending-close-votes) often, and it seems pretty correct, besides the reasons I listed above that may produce differences. It's set to just search for questions that have a close vote reason of unclear what you're asking (*103*), but you can change that to something else, like too broad (*104*) , or primarily opinion based (*105*), etc...

I also use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201658/questions-with-pending-close-votes-off-topic-reasons) which narrows down off topic reasons.